# Enum/Constants defined for NSHTTPURLResponse statusCode?

Tags: ios, http, nshttpurlresponse

Does Foundation (or other 1st party framework) have enum/constants for the NSHTTPURLResponse HTTP statusCode values? For example, something like:

```
NSInteger kHTTPStatusCodeForbidden = 403;
```

Searched through the docs, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can have specific error code for your own specific reason. You can add more error codes depending upon your requirement. So there is no standard enum/constants for these. You can create your own.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for constants for the standard error codes as defined here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html. Does the HTTP protocol not require that the codes defined above always reflect the definitions in rfc2616?

Comment: You can still override it. The web service I use often return "404" when something goes wrong and JSON response having an additional error code and status.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So I guess the answer is no, there are no constants/enums? :)

Comment: ospr: (a) RFC 2616 is obsolete. (b) The set of HTTP method names is extensible, thus enums make little sense. What's relevant is the IANA registry: http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml